# Where can I find the jQuery for place order now button?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, jquery

I'm trying to find the jQuery of the place order button in the onepagecheckout page.

Does anybody know how I can edit the jQuery functionality of the place order button? Please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no jQuery for the place order. Magento 1 uses prototype by default.
The js called by the button is declared in `checkout/onepage/revi8ew/button.phtml` and it is `review.save()`. the code executed is in `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/opcheckout.js`.
Look for the `Review.prototype = {` line and below that you will find the `save` function.

```
save: function(){
    if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
    checkout.setLoadWaiting('review');
    var params = Form.serialize(payment.form);
    if (this.agreementsForm) {
        params += '&'+Form.serialize(this.agreementsForm);
    }
    params.save = true;
    var request = new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl,
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters:params,
            onComplete: this.onComplete,
            onSuccess: this.onSave,
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
        }
    );
},
```